# How to show gizmo grid in Run time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity project where I have created a grid using `OnDrawGizmosSelected()` method. I have a plane 3D gameObject where I have attached the grid.cs script. After saving the script the gizmo shows in the game view, but when I Run my unity project the gizmo is not showing in the run time view. Also the position of the gizmo looks weird, I mean it looks like it's above the plane, but when I see closely the grid is on the plane.

```cs
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    for (float x = 1; x <= 100; x ++)
    {
        for (float z = 1; z <= 65; z ++)
        {
            var point = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, point);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: run time = when you build your project?

Comment: do you select your go during runtime? because OnDrawGizmosSelected() shows only on selecting go

Comment: Gizmos will anyway only show up in the SceneView ... never in the Game View / final build. For the game view / build you should rather use a texture or shader